# Change class style by JavaScript

Tags: styles

I use in the head of a page a `style` tag with definition of the styles used by elements in the body using the ‘class’ attribute.
Example:

```
.itemColor { color:red; }
```

Is it possible, with javascript, to change the value of the `color` property in the classes defined in the tag `style`?

Comment: Thank you.  I presume it's here I have to answer.

Answer (score 0):

For your example, you would first select your item, and then change its style:

```js
    myitem = document.getElementById("itemColor") // searches in all children and grandhildren of document
    myitem.style.color = "blue";
```

You can do the same for the elements in `getElementsByClassName` and `getElementsByTagName`, which are HTML collections.

With the following, you can override all elements' properties having said class.

```js
myitems = document.getElementsByClassName("itemColor")  // HTMLCollection
[].forEach.call(myitems, function(subitem){
        subitem.style.color = "blue";
    }
);
```

`console.log(myitem.style)` to see all attributes you can change.